# the strictly coarser topology

Tags: general-topology, filters

**Let $(X;\tau)$ be $KC$. Let $D = \{ d_{n} : n \in \omega \} \subset X$   countably infnite closed discrete subspace of $X$. Fix $p \in X$ and ultrafilter$\mathcal{F} \in \beta\omega - \omega$ and define
a new topology $\sigma$ on $X$ as follows:
(i) if $p \not\in U$, then $U \in  \sigma $ if and only if $U \in   \tau$ ,
and
(ii) if $p \not\in U$, then $U \in  \sigma $ if and only if $U \in   \tau$  and $ \{n \in \omega : d_{n} \in \mathcal{ F} \}$.**

***I claim that $ \sigma \subset \tau $, because:***

On the one hand if $ p‎ ‎\not\in ‎D‎ $ and $D$ is discrete subspace of $X$ in $\tau$, so there is a nbh $ U  ‎\in ‎\tau ‎‎$ of $p$ such that $ U‎ ‎‎\cap D‎ =‎ ‎‎\emptyset‎‎ $‎. then  ‎$  ‎\{  n  :  ‎d‎_{n}‎\in U‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\} =‎ ‎‎\emptyset ‎\not\in ‎‎\mathcal{F}‎‎ $‎. so 
$ U‎ ‎\not\in‎ ‎\sigma‎ $.

In the othere hand, if $ p‎ ‎=d‎_{n‎_{ 0}‎}‎‎ ‎\in ‎D‎‎$ and $D$ is discrete subspace of $X$ in $\tau$, so there is a nbh $ V  ‎\in ‎\tau ‎‎$ of $p$ such that $ V‎ ‎‎\cap D‎ = ‎\{‎ p‎ ‎\} = ‎‎‎‎\{  ‎d‎_{n‎_{ 0}‎} ‎\}‎ $. Then $ ‎\{  n‎  :‎ ‎d‎_{n}‎‎ ‎\in V‎ ‎‎ ‎\} =‎ ‎\{ ‎n‎_{0}‎‎ ‎\} ‎\not\in ‎‎\mathcal{F}‎‎ $‎, because $\mathcal{F}‎‎ $ is free‎, so $ V‎ ‎\not\in‎ ‎\sigma‎ $‎.

***is my proof right?***

Answer (score 0):

You meant to say that if $p\notin U$, then $U\in\sigma$ if and only if $U\in\tau$ and $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in U\}\in\mathscr{F}$. Once you make that correction, your proof will be fine.